# Why is this bar in musescore the wrong length

Tags: musescore

I was working on this sheet in musescore but I got up to the second bar in this image and it seems to be the wrong length for the time signature. If I try to add quarter notes to it I can only fit in 3 and if I attempt to delete the bar it just messes up the next one. What would be causing this and how can I fix it?

[image]

The version of musescore used is

> OS: Linux 5.1.16-300.fc30.x86_64, Arch.: x86_64, MuseScore version
>   (64-bit): 3.2.3., revision: github-musescore-musescore-d2d863f

Comment: MIght help if you post the source used to build this. (and that grey overbar on the quarter-rest hints at something screwed up)      BTW,   us performers would rather see a staccato  8th or 16th note there.  If you need it reallly short, label the passage "staccatissimo"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Added in that extra info. Also big thanks for the staccato tip, I was sure there was a better way of doing this :P

Comment: Why does this rest need any accent at all? I think this is the problem that Carl is pointing out: the tenuto dash means that this  rest is longer than 100% and this may hinder you to notate another additional note.

Comment: Have you tried deleting **all** bars from broken bar to end and then adding the requisite number of bars again? Of course if you've entered notes there it's a bigger headache

Comment: How does one play an accented rest?!

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without having the actual .mscz file to look at.
If you want, send it to me privately by email.  My website is easy to find (I'm the live musician, not the dead actor of the same name) and my email address is prominently displayed.  If I can sort it out I'll post the solution for everyone's benefit.

Comment: I would not interpret the grey line as an accent, it would be black if it were an accent.  Did you start in one time sig then change later?  Or have you changed the state of the score in any meaningful way after initialization?  Other than a true source code bug that's all I can think of.  Some of these programs hold on to stale state data and it is not obvious how to recover the initial state.

Comment: Try the user manual (open source is not always great in this area)

Comment: @ggcg I've been hit by this musescore bug when I changed a time signature midstream

Comment: @Rusi, me too.  Though I don't know enough to be helpful, hence no answer.  I just start over.

Comment: @ggcg Better than starting over is piecemeal copy pasting.  Of course if you *literally* have just 2 notes followed by buggy bar you might as well start over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit bars to have a different time value to the written time signature, which may be what you have done here. To correct this, you have to modify the actual bar value.

1. Right click on the bar, and select `Bar Properties`:

   [image: right click on bar]
2. Change the `Actual` value from `3` to `4`:

   [image: hand-drawn square]
3. Your bar should now be four beats.

[Read all about it](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/3/measure-operations#properties) in the handbook!

Comment: Yeah, the blue - above the 2nd bar suggests that particular measure has a custom time set.